1つのPC(Windows)に対してBLEキーボードを複数接続するには？
質問詳細
BleKeyboardというライブラリを使ってESP32でBLEキーボードを作ったのですが、同じファームウェアを書き込んだキーボードを1つのPC(Windows)に繋ごうとすると、2台目以降は繋げられません(最初は一瞬繋がるがそれ以降は繋がらない)。どのようにすれば複数台繋げられそうでしょうか。
周辺情報

最初につなげたキーボードとのペアリング情報をPC側で削除してやると、別のキーボードを繋ぐことができます。
ライブラリのソースコードを読んでいくと、VenderIDやProductIDというものがありますが、それらやキーボードの名前をキーボードごとに変えても症状は変わりません。
MacOSだと複数接続できます。
Linuxは試していません。


「マルチペアリング対応」か「ロジクールUnifyingレシーバー」というのがキーワードらしいですよ。1台のPCに2つのBluetoothマウスを同時接続することができますか, Bluetoothは複数接続できる？複数接続の基本とマルチポイント機能にいて解説！, Bluetoothは複数接続できる？ 『マルチペアリング』『マルチポイント』など違いを解説, USB Unifyingレシーバー
